# apache rewriterule causing redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Im trying to make an apache(2) RewriteRule which is using a QUERY_STRING to redirect a user to a friendly to read URL, but it is causing a redirect loop.

What I want to achieve is that when a user requests for the `index.php?layout=751&artnr=#` URL, that this request gets redirected to `/another/page/#`.

And in a way the Redirect works, but Apache keeps redirecting the user once it has reached the `/another/page` page

The RewriteRule looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^layout=751&artnr=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ another/page/%1? [R=301,L]
```

I've been searching alot of issues about this situation but none of them really have the answer that solves my problem, since those problems don't use a QUERY_STRING.

I have also tried to add the `RewriteOptions maxredirects=1` option, but this doesn't solve the problem either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?layout=751&artnr=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ another/page/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

This assumes a `RewriteBase` has been set above this rule.

Clear your browser cache or use a new browser to test this change.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it finally works! And also thanks for the explanation so I understand how it works.

Comment: You have accepted the answer, that is good enough. Soon you will have 15 rep points to be able to upvote any answer.